# Javascript for dynamically revealing Django formset forms

Tags: javascript, django

I'm trying to add/remove forms from formsets dynamically on button press. I am looking at an [older example](https://www.brennantymrak.com/articles/django-dynamic-formsets-javascript.html) for JS to perform this action but I have multiple formsets but when I delete all of the forms for one of the formsets, obviously the addForm command no longer works as there are no forms to clone.

That being said, I think a functional method would be to start with a hidden form and then copy the hidden form and display that form on demand. I just don't know how exactly to do that.

Ideally, I'd like to not show any forms until the button press but not certain about how to do it. My current setup is shown below.

HTML:

```
<div class="selection">
  <div class="forms">
    <!-- {% for dict in formset.errors %}
      {% for error in dict.values %}
        {{ error }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %} -->

    <form id="general-formset" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}

      {{ generalFormset.management_form }}
      {% for form in generalFormset %}
      <div class="formset">
        {{ form.as_table }}
        <button id="remove-form" type="button" onclick="removeForm(this)" display="None">Remove Constraint</button>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
      <button id="add-form" type="button" onclick="addForm(this)">Add Constraint</button>
    </form>

    <form id="specific-formset" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}

      {{ specificFormset.management_form }}
      {% for form in specificFormset %}
      <div class="formset">
        {{ form.as_table }}
        <button id="remove-form" type="button" onclick="removeForm(this)">Remove Constraint</button>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
      <button id="add-form" type="button" onclick="addForm(this)" display="None">Add Constraint</button>
    </form>
    <button id="submit" type="button">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
  let submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit")

  submitButton.addEventListener('click', submitForms)

  function submitForms(e){
    document.getElementById("specific-formset").submit();
    document.getElementById("general-formset").submit();
  }

  function addForm(e){
    let container = e.parentElement
    let form = container.querySelectorAll(".formset")[0].cloneNode(true)
    let formNum = container.querySelectorAll(".formset").length-1
    let formRegex = RegExp(`form-(\\d){1}-`,'g')
    let totalForms = container.querySelector("#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS")

    formNum++
    form.innerHTML = form.innerHTML.replace(formRegex, `form-${formNum}-`)
    container.insertBefore(form, e)
        
    totalForms.setAttribute('value', `${formNum+1}`)
  }
  
  function removeForm(e){
    let parent = e.parentElement
    let container = parent.parentElement
    let formNum = container.querySelectorAll(".formset").length-1
    let totalForms = container.querySelector("#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS")
      
    parent.remove()
    formNum--
    totalForms.setAttribute('value', `${formNum-1}`)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: In HTML you have the [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) element in which you can output HTML without it being rendered. You can output your form in it and copy the contents of the template element whenever you want to add a new form.

Comment: Any ideas on how that would work with a formset? The hidden forms aspect of the formset needs to be instantiated as far as I'm aware so would I remove the django for loop and just use 1 form and set that within the <template> tag to be added with the button?

Comment: hey first off you generally only need one csrf token and i noticed you're using pure javascript , why?

Comment: Because I don't know what I'm doing

Answer (score 0):

ok to summerize formsets in django is something i use to use alot when i starting professionally coding but ive realized when youre creating 10s of instances its not viable but ive lookup this old code for you and will try to explain it.

generally formsets have a management header used to keep track of all forms, the max , the min and thus we need to ensure we are not creating for forms that the manager dictates shouldnt be. so my advice when instantiating the formset make sure your max form is an amount you will never cross. also to simplify it start off with a default of one.

now to summerize the code below it takes the last form and copies it and changes the ids of each div, element and increases it based on the last number in the list so if youve had 5 forms when you press add more it will create a few form form ending 6

```
function updateElementIndex(el, prefix, ndx) {
var id_regex = new RegExp('(' + prefix + '-\\d+)');
var replacement = prefix + '-' + ndx;
if ($(el).attr("for")) $(el).attr("for", $(el).attr("for").replace(id_regex, replacement));
if (el.id) el.id = el.id.replace(id_regex, replacement);
if (el.name) el.name = el.name.replace(id_regex, replacement);
}


function cloneMore(selector, prefix) {
var newElement = backup;
var total = $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
var hiddenvalue;
newElement.find(":input:not([type=button]):not([type=submit]):not([type=reset])").each(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name')
    var vvalue = $(this).attr('value')

    if(name) {
        name = name.replace('-' + (total-1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
        var id = 'id_' + name + total;
        $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id, 'value':vvalue}).val('').removeAttr('checked');
    }
    if(vvalue) {
        hiddenvalue = vvalue;
    }
});

newElement.find('div').each(function() {
    var fordiv = $(this).attr('id');
    if (fordiv) {
        fordiv = fordiv.replace('-' + (total-1)+ '-', '-' + total + '-');
        $(this).attr({'id': fordiv});

    }
});

newElement.find('label').each(function() {
    var forValue = $(this).attr('for');
    if (forValue) {
      forValue = forValue.replace('-' + (total-1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
      $(this).attr({'for': forValue});
    }
});
newElement.find('input[type=hidden]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr({'value':hiddenvalue});
});

total++;
backup = newElement;
$('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);
$(newElement).clone().insertAfter(".form-row:last");

var conditionRow = $('.form-row:not(:last)');
conditionRow.find('.btn.add-form-row')
.removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
.removeClass('add-form-row').addClass('remove-form-row')
.html('-');
return false;
}


function deleteForm(prefix, btn) {
var total = parseInt($('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
if (total > 1){
    btn.closest('.form-row').remove();
    var forms = $('.form-row');
    $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(forms.length);
    for (var i=0, formCount=forms.length; i<formCount; i++) {
        $(forms.get(i)).find(':input').each(function() {
            updateElementIndex(this, prefix, i);
        });
    }
}
return false;
}

$(document).on('click', '.add-form-row', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
cloneMore('.form-row:last', 'form');
return false;
});


$(document).on('click', '.remove-form-row', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
deleteForm('form', $(this));
return false;
});
```

Comment: also i am using jquery